# AnimatedImage in compose multiplatform giving NoClassDefFoundError on Android but works on Desktop

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I am using the AnimatedImage class in the compose [multiplatform components library](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/tree/master/components/AnimatedImage). It works perfectly to show a gif on Desktop but when I run this code on Android it crashes with this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/compose/ui/res/Resources_desktopKt;                                                                                                     
    at org.jetbrains.compose.animatedimage.ResourceAnimatedImageLoader$generateByteArray$2.invokeSuspend(ResourceAnimatedImageLoader.kt:12)
```

I have the resources in the common module in `resource/drawable`

I also have the sources set correctly for Android by including both `res` and `resources`. I know this works because I can access a .jpg file from drawable on both platforms.

The code snippet that crashes looks like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Pony() {
    Image(
        loadOrNull { loadResourceAnimatedImage("drawable/pony.gif") }?.animate() ?: ImageBitmap.Blank,
        contentDescription = null,
        Modifier.size(100.dp)
    )
}
```

Comment: Please register this as a issue https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues/new/choose